# Save Footprints from PCB in Altium

Tags: altium, footprint

I have a script that convert Eagle PCB to Altium PCB. It creates the components, tracks, pads, etc. Everything works ok. I can click on "component" like the resistor footprint, and move it, etc.

Now, I would like to include those components onto my own footprint library, but I cannot find how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Altium Design->Make PCB Library

[image]

Comment: i see, i have to make a lib, then copy and paste to my own library

Answer (score 2):

Definitely covered in the Altium manuals somewhere. Have you searched?

Anyways, go to the PCB. Click the Design menu, and "Make PCB library".

You are done.